# Javascript setTimeOut in For Loop Behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am curious as to why and how the javascript interpreter outputs the following

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

When running this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
setTimeout(function(){console.log(i);},200);  
};
```

Can anyone provide a thorough explanation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to do with chronology.

Remember the timeout is a synchronous operation that is delayed, so by the time it runs, it consults `i` and finds its value to be 5. This is because the last action of the (synchronous) loop was to set its value to 5: it reached 4 (the last iteration of the loop) and then the `i++` made it 5.

If you want to output 0-4 but retain the timeout, you need to capture the current, iterative value of `i` at the time you create your timeout. You can do this by passing it into an immediately-executing function:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    setTimeout((function(i) { return function(){ console.log(i); }; })(i),200);
```

Comment: To put it simply, the closure remembers the reference to a variable, not the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps to see that in the original example the closest scope for variable i, when called inside log , it's the global scope.Considering that and the fact that the for and setimeout are synchronous operations , executed one after each other, i gets to 5 and only after that is logged.